# Inject DbContext to repository based on the generic type using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, simple-injector

Consider I have the following generic class:

```cs
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext Context { get; set; }

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}
```

And I register two different dbcontext as below, using SimpleInjector :

```cs
container.Register<ContextA>(
    ()=> new ContextA(SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), sqlConnection).Options));

container.Register<ContextB>(
    () => new ContextB(SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), sqlConnection).Options));
```

And then I have the following registration for dbContext :

```cs
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(DbContext),
    typeof(ContextA),
    c=> c.Consumer.ImplementationType.GenericTypeArguments
        .Any(r => r.Namespace == "NameSpace.ContextA"));

container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(DbContext),
    typeof(ContextB),
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType.GenericTypeArguments
        .Any(r => r.Namespace == "NameSpace.ContextB"));
```

When the codes reaches **container.RegisterConditional** it throws error and complains about a `ContextA` having two constructor.

Considering that I have already injected `ContextA` and `ContextB`, what is the best way to inject appropriate `DbContext` for `Repository` based on its generic argument value?

**Update**

I want to inject `DbContext` to `Repository<T>`, based on the type passed to initialize the `Repository<T>`.

So I might have:

```cs
IRepository<Entity1> ...
```

Which `Entity1` could be in **NameSpace.ContextA**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `RegisterConditional` overload that accepts a `Registration`. This way you can wrap the lambda expression inside the `Registration` as follows:

```cs
var contextARegistration =
    Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(
        () => new ContextA(
            SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), sqlConnection).Options),
        container);

container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(DbContext),
    contextARegistration,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType.GenericTypeArguments
             .Any(r => r.Namespace == "NameSpace.ContextA"));

var contextBRegistration =
    Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(
        () => new ContextB(
            SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), sqlConnection).Options),
        container);

container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(DbContext),
    contextBRegistration,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType.GenericTypeArguments
             .Any(r => r.Namespace == "NameSpace.ContextB"));
```

Comment: Ok, I have one problem. It seems that the way I have used to detect type for Generic paramter of Reposotiry, is not correct. Because I am getting  "Multiple applicable registrations found for DbContext. The applicable registrations are ..." Erorr. What should I use instead of "GenericTypeArguments"

Comment: Please update your question with the details (stack trace, etc) of the error.